# How can I compute $\int_{\mathbb R}f(x,y)\mathbb P(X\in dx, |X|\in dy)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$. I want to find the join distribution of $(X,|X|)$ is given by

$$F(x,y)=\mathbb P(X\leq x,|X|\leq y)=\mathbb P(X\leq x,-y\leq X\leq y)=\mathbb P(-y\leq X\leq \min(x,y))$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_y^{\min(x,y)}e^{-u^2/2}du.$$

Since $(X,|X|)$ has no density nor mass function, I can't get $\mathbb P(X\in dx, |X|\in dy)$. But is there a way to get $\mathbb P(X\in dx,|X|\in dy)$ so that I can compute $$\int_{\mathbb R}f(x,y)\mathbb P(X\in dx,Y\in dy)\ \ ?$$

(may be as sort of Lebesgue/radon decomposition of the measure $\mathbb P(X\in dx, |X|\in dy)$.

Comment: The distribution of $(X,|X|)$ is cumulated on whole curve $y=|x|$ so there is neither density nor pmf

Comment: but can we get at least the measure $\mu(dxdy)=\mathbb P(X\in dx,|X|\in dy)$ ?

Comment: You have already obtained the joint distribution in line 3 of the post.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: But I need to compute something as $\int f(x,y)\mu(dxdy)$ where $\mu(dxdy)=\mathbb P(X\in dx,|X|\in dy)$ how can I do if I just have the 3 equality ?

Comment: CDF determines distribution uniquelly, so you got it. If you want "other" form, you can look at cases when set $U$ is included in curve $y=x$ for $x>0$. Then you'll get "density" on that part of linear subspace. The same with another branch of $y=|x|$ which is symetric due to symmetry of $N(0,1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your random vector $(X,|X|)$ is cumulated on the whole curve $y=|x|$, so tu find it's distribution it is enought to consider subsets of $V= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : y=|x| \}$. Let $V_+ = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2_+ : y = x \}$. Due to symmetry of $\mathcal N(0,1)$ distribution it is enough to consider $V_+$. So take any $A \subset V_+$ borel. Let $\mu$ be distribution of $(X,|X|)$

You have  $$\mu(A) = \mathbb P((X,|X|) \in A) = \mathbb P (X \in \pi_1(A \cap V_+))=\int_{\pi_1(A \cap V_+)} \varphi(x)dx$$
where $\varphi$ is density of $\mathcal N(0,1)$. Similarly with $B \subset V_- := V\setminus V_+$ borel, we get:

$$\mu(B) = \mathbb P((X,|X|) \in B) = \mathbb P(X \in \pi_1(B \cap V_-)) = \int_{\pi_1(B \cap V_-)}\varphi(x)dx$$ which isn't surprising due to symmetry.

That means, taking now any $C \subset \mathbb R^2$ borel, we have the distribution in the form:
$$ \mu(C) = \mu(C \cap V) = \int_{\pi_1(C \cap V)} \varphi(x)dx $$

**Edit:** 
Now to calculate that integral:

Take any $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ borel. You want to compute $\mathbb E[f(X,|X|)]$.

Note that $$\mathbb E[f(X,|X|)] = \int_{\mathbb R^2} f(x,y)\mu(dx,dy) $$

Since $\mu$ is cumulated on $V$, we in fact have:

$$ \mathbb E[f(X,|X|)] = \int_{V} f(x,y)\mu(dx,dy) = \int_{\pi_1(V_+)}f(x,x)\mu_X(dx) + \int_{\pi_1(V_-)}f(x,-x) \mu_X(dx)$$

Where $\mu_X$ is the distribution of variable $\mathcal N(0,1)$. Since in has density, we can get (note that $\pi_1(V_+) = \mathbb R_+$ and $\pi_1(V_-) = \mathbb R_-$ ):

$$ \mathbb E[f(X,|X|)] = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x,|x|)\varphi(x)dx $$

**EDIT 2** If you're interested only in calculating $\mathbb E[f(X,|X|)]$ you can define $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by $g(x) = f(x,|x|)$. Then:

$$\mathbb E[f(X,|X|)] = \mathbb E[g(X)] = \int_{\mathbb R} g(x)\varphi(x)dx = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x,|x|)\varphi(x)dx $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my question (just in case).

Comment: @Walace I've edited